# how to pass value from one page to another page in oracle apex 5.0?

Tags: oracle, button, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have two form pages 3 and 4. I want to pass the value for item: P3_LOT_N in page 3 to item: P4_LOT_N in page 4 when the button "Next" is pressed. How can I do this in oracle apex 5.0? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

- open NEXT button's properties
- under "Behavior", set "Action" property to "Redirect to page in this application"
- click the button next to the "Target" (currently, it says "No link defined")
- in a modal window that opens, target page will be Page 4
- in "Set items" section, set "Name - value" pair (i.e. set P4_LOT_N to accept P3_LOT_N value)

That should be all.

Comment: Note that this will use the value of P3_LOT_N as it was when the page is loaded. If that is a form element the user can change, you'll probably want a Submit + Branch, instead.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  Adding an "Action" to the button "NEXT" works but only if I remove the "PROCESS ROW OFRW_LOT_SUMMARY" that I have in the form.

Comment: I want to be able to save the records into the database and then hit "NEXT" and redirect the P3_LOT_N value to the next form P4_LOT_N.  Currently I have a 'CREATE' button that updates and inserts the records in the form into the database. After that process is done, I want the user to hit the 'NEXT' button and mopve onto a new form that will contain the same LOT_N that was entered in the previous form.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this via a "Redirect to page in this application", then the other form values you have on page 3 will not be POSTed to session state.

There are at least a couple other ways you could accomplish this:

- You could simply have the Source of item P4_LOT_N be P3_LOT_N.
- You could define a computation on page 3, to set P4_LOT_N to P3_LOT_N.